# Call a defined function in lambda in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to understand the mechanics of user defined functions (UDF) and the difference that using a lambda function makes when creating a new column in a dataframes, based on multiple conditions across all rows in two more more columns.

I tried a few different ways, but only some of it works. I'd like to understand why the other parts of the code don't work and what I need to change to make it work. In particular, I need an efficient way to call a UDF to create a new column in a large dataframe. It's easier to communicate the idea and issues using this smaller dataframe.

Define the DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'], 
               'B': ['qux', 'quux', 'quuz', 'xyz']})
df
```

First, the lines that do work:

```
df['col2'] = (df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'qux' )
df = df.assign(col3 = lambda x: (df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'qux' ))
```

The resulting columns col2 and col3 are correct; only the first row is True, the rest false as expected. However, the conditions can become more complicated as there could be many more columns (in the real code; the concept would be the same, so easier to use this example here) - so I thought I'd create a separate UDF and try to call it. This doesn't work.

```
def test(df):
    if (  (df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'qux' ) ).any():
        x = True
    else:
        x = False
    return x
```

The results on 'col1' and col4 are incorrect - they both return TRUE for all rows. I'm not sure why and would appreciate some guidance here.

```
df['col1'] = test(df)              
df = df.assign(col4 = lambda x: test(df))
```

Again, the only reason I'm using a separate UDF is that I anticipate the filtering conditions to get more convoluted.....so the code is cleaner if I use a different function and just call it in. Seems like I'll have to use a loop for the DF....but that will get so inefficient with a large data set.

I also tried this, but the results are unchanged:

```
df = df.assign(col5 = df.apply(lambda x: test(df), axis=1))
```

Here's a picture of the output; only the highlighted yellow columns here are correct. Not sure why the other lines of code don't work.

[image: code output]

Update: this worked. Now, the function correctly looks at the condition for each row and labels them (peak, bad, offpeak) correctly.

```
def test3(row):
x = True
if (( row['A'] == 'foo') & (row['B'] == 'qux') ):
    x = False
elif ( (row['A'] == 'foo') & (row['B'] == 'xyz') ):
    x = 'NA'
return x  


df['col'] = df.apply(lambda x: test3(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I suspect it's the use of ".any()" that may be causing the bad result.....but if I don't use it, I get "...truth value of a series is ambiguous...." error.

Comment: I think that (some) of the problems are because you are confusing between `any ` and `all` - you want both conditions to be true, so you should use `all`.

Comment: @TDG - I'm afraid the result is still wrong......nowCol 4 and 5 are FALSE everywhere. I tried that...but did not post the result.....appreciate your feedback though!

Comment: In a second thought, why are you using `any`? The `any` functions "Return whether any element is True" and in your case of strings, if the values are not null then it is true. I think that you should omit the `any` - `def test(df): return (df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'qux' )`

Comment: @TDG  - thanks...this does work.....but the ultimate goal was to have multiple conditions with if, elif and else. So I thought I would have to use the relevant statements...and if I don't use .any with the first if statement, I get a "truth value of series is ambiguous" error. In addition, I may want to use other strings instead of the boolean True and False, example the value x may become 'pass' or 'fail' etc., so I was trying to be as general as possible....and this explicitly writing out the IF ELIF ELSE conditions.

Comment: I guess it depends on your real data. Just remember that if you have strings like - `s = None` or `s = ""` they will be eveluated to False. All other values are True.

Comment: @TDG - thanks......but say  I want to use return "pass" if the condition is true, "fail" if false   else "NA" if none of the conditions are met....how would I modify the code? That's where I 'm trying to get to.

Comment: I think that you should post a new question with a detailed example of the inputs that you have and the desired output for each of them.